# How to let tkinter treeview fit your frame

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, frame

I want my treeview to fully fit the geometry size of my window have defined for my GUI but the display doesn't cover the entire window been display in the middle.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1200x680+50+20")


tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.insert("", "0", "item1", text="LANGUAGE")
tree.insert("", "1", "item2", text="GUI")
tree.insert("item1", "0", text="pyhton")

#SUb treeview
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure("Treeview", rowheight=70)
tree.configure(style="Treeview")

    ############
tree.config(columns=("NOTE", "book"))   # this creates to seperate headings 
for treeview
tree.column("NOTE", width=300)
tree.heading("NOTE", text="Info")
tree.column("book", width=300)
tree.heading("book", text="profile")


tree.set("item1", "NOTE","Am using python version 3.6.1 \n on windows 
machine")
tree.set("item2","NOTE","This an example Tkinter Treeview in Python, which 
is from \nttk class make sure import ttk\n also from tkinter import *")


tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I tried to put it in a Frame but that doesn't  also display the content for the treeview. This the code

```
fr = tk.Frame(root, width=1200, height=680, relief="groove") 

tree = ttk.Treeview(fr)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please replace the following line

```
tree.pack()
```

with following line

```
tree.pack(fill='x')
```

This will use the COMPLETE SPACE of ROOT screen.

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Comment: @ Fuzed Mass Thanks very much it means by default the pack fills the (y-axis)

Comment: yes, welcome. please upvote my answer and mark is complete. thanks.

Comment: so why cant  both y and x axis be placed in the pack any reason for that. Asking this because when i change the theme if fills the x axis by default

Comment: try using:
tree.pack(fill='both')

Comment: correction: `fill=x` means it will use the full _width_ of the window, not necessarily the height.

Comment: @AD_WAN: not, widgets do not by default fill the  y-axis. It may _appear_ that they do, but if you resize the window or add more widgets you'll see that widgets don't automatically fill in either direction. You simply created a widget that was too big to fit, so it looked like it filled in the y axis.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: thanks for the hints, but when you call the treeview as toplevel window it doesn't fill the enter window.Have used fill both and fill x any suggestion to do that.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "call the treeview as toplevel window" -- you can't "call" a treeview, and it's not a toplevel window. However, to get it to fill in both directions, use `fill='both'`.

Comment: Have created a button  which opens the treeview when you click on it,the treeview pops up as a toplevel. Have used the fill="both" it doesn't fill both directions.

Comment: still not filling with `fill="both"` and `fill="x"`  any idea?